# Don't immediately see the point behind this (php, school)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a 2nd year ICT student. I never did PHP before this year and our instructor gave us the basics and at the end of the semester, gave us a project that would combine what we learned in his course and the databases course. We were to use the classic AMP setup on windows.

Now, our instructor told us to make a profile-site, based on how we made smaller ones before in class.

I don't see the point behind the somewhat weird method of entering the user into the database.

First, we do some PHP formchecking to make sure the entered data is safe and somewhat realistic(for instance, zip-codes over here are 4 numbers, never more and no letters or other symbols).

When everything checks out fine, we do  the following:

```
$sql = new SqlObject(); //from SqlObject.class.php
$newUser = new User(login,passw,mail,...,...,...); //from User.class.php
$sql->addUser($newUser);
```

The SqlObject class is a class that contains all the SQL commands we need update, insert and generally alter data in the database. We never write SQL in our *normal* pages. But that's not what I'm confused about. It's the User.class.php file.

This file contains only a constructor and exactly the same amount of fields as needs to be entered into the database. For instance:

```
<?php

  class User {
    // members
    var $id;
    var $name;
    var $password;

    // constructor
    function User($id=-1,$name='',$password='') {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->password = $password;
    }
}

?>
```

That's it. The SqlObject.class.php file requires the User.class.php file on the first line.

The function `addUser($user)` in the SqlObject.class.php file looks like this:

```
function addUser($user) {
  $insQuery = 'INSERT INTO users(name,password)';
  $insQuery.= " VALUES ('".$user->name."', '".$user->password."')";
  @mysql_query($insQuery) or showError("user insert failed");
}
```

Why make such a detour via the User.class.php file? Security reason of some kind?

I'll repeat: It's my first year using PHP and I'm still a student.

EDIT: People are complaining that there is no checks on SQL injection before inserting the data.

At the beginning of this post, I mentioned "formchecking".
The `register.php` file does all the escaping and checking of input. This includes several Regex tests, mysql_real_escape_string() and some simpler tests.
Once all tests are passed and all input is escaped, only then will this happen:

```
$sql = new SqlObject(); //from SqlObject.class.php
$newUser = new User(login,passw,mail,...,...,...); //from User.class.php
$sql->addUser($newUser);
```

That code is never executed if the input doesn't receive the treatment that I see some people wanting to give it inside the SqlObject.class.php file.

EDIT2: as promised, blog [posted](http://webdevhobo.blogspot.com/2009/08/prepared-statements-in-php.html)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming ?

Comment: Why not ask your instructors - that's what they are getting paid for.

Comment: They claimed it was a nice way to get us to realize that PHP is capable of OO-programming.

Comment: +1 Excellent question (and good tutorage). I'm pleased to see PHP being taught. Question everything in the pursuit of knowledge, you'll go far!

Comment: @WebDevHobo: with regard to one of your comments, I'd like to stress again that the proper place to make sure the strings are safe to use in SQL is in the `User` class. Think about it. You've just abstracted away all SQL related code from `register.php`, except for the safe string checks? Perhaps users are not stored in a MySQL database at all. It's clearly the `User` class' responsibility. Also, having a `showError` call in `addUser` is bad design. Throw an exception, return an error code.. anything but showing the error itself. That is for `register.php` to handle.

Comment: I'll be adding a blogpost to clarify a bit more on this. I'll be posting the link soon.

Comment: \*shrug\* clarify all you want, but you will still be just as wrong :P

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - I think it's been an illuminating question, I'm glad it came here.

Comment: "This includes ... mysql_real_escape_string()". Bad. You should be using bound parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you're asking why not just pass the user and password in directly

```
 function addUser($name='',$password='') { etc
```

My guess is that the code you show is an example of future-proofing, the idea being that the User class might do something a lot more detailed in the future, or get the credentials from some other source, rather than having name and password passed to its constructor.

It's an idea of separation of concerns, some bit if code is responsible for assembling the suer data, the addUer function merely uses the stuff it needs. In large programs it really helps to have these kinds of organisation - on the surface it might appear to be adding complexity but when you start to think like this it enables you limit the number of pieces you need to keep in your head. Also you might imagine breaking up the overall programming task so one person looks at the User class, another does the addUser. They can work independently. Silly in this tiny case, but in the real world very beneficial.

Comment: That makes sense. It's a class after all. And you can do a lot more than just pass arguments around. I never considered alternate sources of data influencing the data I'm gonna put in my database.

Comment: Also think about cases where other function can make use of the User class, like PrintUser() or similar...

Comment: If this is about separation of concerns, remove that `showError` call from `addUser` *on the double*. Ew.

Comment: @Thorain, that's good advice, but it might be fair to cut a little slack. WebDevHobo is trying to understand the original program structure. He's not claiming that this is an example of perfect separation of concerns.

Comment: The showError function is just a little something I use in the template we've been given. It replaces the white error page with a somewhat more friendly page. A cleaned up die() to be blunt. Anyway, I posted a link, as promised.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the addUser() method is awful, allows sql injections because it doesn't use prepared statements nor escapes the contents. It should read something like

```
function addUser($user) {
  $insQuery = 'INSERT INTO users(name,password)';
  $insQuery.= " VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($user->name)."',";
  $insQuery.= " '".mysql_real_escape_string($user->password)."')";
  @mysql_query($insQuery) or showError("user insert failed");
}
```

This is awful because it teaches you bad practices, your teacher should teach you about SQL injections from day one, and not simplify them just for academic sake.

That aside, the idea is to future proof the code, using abstractions.

Abstractions allow you to think in a higher level. At this current level the User class might seem overkill, because it acts only as a storage facility, but it helps you think in term of domain instances instead of SQL sentences which then will help you make modifications shall such a need arise.

These abstractions also create a single place to complexify the code without having the changes spread all over, for example if you'd then need something else about a user you need only change the User class, for example by adding a, say, printUser() method or whatever.

```
function printUser() {
    return "Mr. ".$this->name;
}
```

But this being an easy and artificial academic example, it might not make much sense. You'd need a bigger scenario to really see the benefit of abstractions.

About your edits:

I'm glad that you are told about SQL injections, even if not in the right place :)

The proper place to do the escaping for SQL injection is not in a previous 'formchecking' step, but to do it when sending the data to the SQL server. That 'formchecking' is the proper place to validate as you say, length of zipcodes, or empty fields and so on, but not to escape the strings to be SQL safe.

A simple example should show why:

```
$name = formcheck("John O'Donnell"); //Where you do all your checking step,
                                     //including mysql_real_escape_string
$user = new User($name,"gandalf");
```

But,

```
mysql_real_escape_string("John O'Donnell") = "John O\'Donnell";
```

Now you use your User instance to display the name on the screen:

```
 echo "Welcome ".$user->printUser();
```

and you get:

```
Welcome Mr. John O\'Donell
```

Comment: You added 2 functions to turn it from awful to good. I call that exaggerating. Also, I mentioned in my original post that there is formchecking, and only when the test(s) is/are passed, can the data move on to be inserted into the database. The escaping and checking for injections happen in register.php, not in SqlObject.class.php, because the class is meant for managing the database, not to perform security checks.

Comment: Also, the abstraction thing is kinda new to me, but seems like a smart way to to make sure you can improve your code without having to completely re-write it each time.

Comment: Two things: 1.- Is the formchecking checking for all the SQL injection vectors? I doubt it. The proper place to do either the escaping or the prepared statements is where the data is being sent to the SQL server, even after all the manual checks you can think about. Anything else is bad practice and risky. Teaching that to youngsters is irresponsible in my opinion. 2.- Of course that abstractions are a smart way to handle complexity, and that's its benefit. I'm just saying that the benefit is not apparent from such a simple example, which is what lead to your question.

Comment: "The proper place to do either the escaping or the prepared statements is where the data is being sent to the SQL server". I do not agree with that and I don't see why I should. Waiting for the very last moment to do escaping or use prepared statements is a bad thing to do, since the file in which it is done isn't meant for it. A file to check the data, a file to insert the data. Not one file where it gets checked and then inserted. That's a bad separation of functionality.

Comment: Also, I just now read your example on Mr. O'Donnel. We've been informed about this and the trick is to be consistent. I'll make a blogpost about it. Fair warning about my blog: don't be surprised if you find the subjects to be small in scale and amateurish, I never intended it to be more then a way for me to think about the stuff I see in classes or post some random programming-related stuff. I'll be up in half an hour if Blogpost doesn't deny service. Link is on my profile.

Comment: Escaping has nothing to do with checking validity of data. It is merely a conversion to the format required by MySQL. Posting here was a good idea, but if you're not going to accept what *everybody* is telling you, then it is a waste of effort ;)

Comment: @WebDevHobo: The point is not *wait until the last moment* to do SQL escaping but to *do it where it matters*. If you do it someplace else (before) you have to start writing blogposts about your supposed consistency and make extra efforts to get the data in the supposed format. The thing is that the **ONLY PLACE SQL ESCAPING MATTERS is in the SQL server**, no place else. You should, as I said, validate content (zip code formats, empty fields, valid email addresses and so on) before because that matters to the whole application, but SQL string escaping is just not that case. [continues...]

Comment: [...continued] Also, I wonder what exactly you meant by "a file that wasn't meant for it". If you have a class handling SQL sentences to do reads and writes to a database, I have a really hard time telling why SQL escaping doesn't belong there. Also, it's better to talk in terms of classes than to talk in terms of files. It's a good practice to keep a single class per file, but file is not the unit to talk about.

Comment: @WebDevHobo: It seems to me that you are mixing domain data validation with sql escaping. Those are two totally different things.

Comment: Vinko, I think I get what you're saying now. Indeed, I was mixing these things. Having read this after I wrote the blog, I wanna go and delete over half the stuff I wrote for realizing how incredibly stupid it makes me sound :(  I just hope that being a student allows me to make a mistake every now and then... Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It may not make as much sense since the project is small. But you now have a user class in which you could add more functions to use everywhere else. Such as a function to check if a username exists, update, delete ect.

It also makes it so that you can reuse this code in the next project since its more robust. Say in the next project you need to write something bigger such as a full user management system. You would then realize how nice it is to split things up.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I thought it was to prevent SQL-Injections, but as there is no validation of the input, this isn't the case either. So only for future addititions to the functionality is a possibility.

Did you learn to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) in the database class? Because this is really needed to protect your database from attacks!

**Update to reflect OP's edit:** I still dont feel comfortable about the sanatizing of the input. An UI or GUI is for one purpose only: Display data. The businesslayer (this would be your User class) cares about the sanatizing, before it sends the data to the datalayer (your sqlobject class). Please think about it and maybe talk to it with your instructors.

Comment: Fixed your formatting. You can use underscores if your text is surrounded by backquotes (inline code). You can also escape them with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a sample of OO in PHP, then it's a bad one. Why? Because the SqlObject contains a method AddUser(), which suggests the class is directly linked to the User class. You could derive an SqlUser class from SqlObject and use that class to add users instead. This new class would handle the communications with the database and would also be responsible to prevent any SQL injections. Even though you can escape any attempts of code injection in other locations, it should still be included in this class, just in case you forget to add a call somewhere else. (Don't think that won't happen, because it will!)

However, there is a reason for keeping things a bit simpler, even though it costs reliability in the final code. This is a school project and therefore an example of how to write code. It's reasonable robust for a simple project, even though there's a lot of room for improvements. Also, keep in mind that you're learning in a controlled environment. Once you start to work for a commercial company, things should look a lot better. (And unfortunately, at quite a few companies, things are just far worse.)

Comment: I see no suggestion of the two being linked. Perhaps this is something only you think when you look at it. Also, an SqlUser class? To have that class contains all methods that concern the user? I guess so. It would be a clear way of separating functionality. Sadly, we're under strict orders not to deviate from the given files. We can edit them a bit with our own custom functions, but we're not allowed to make extras. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

if the AddUser class is inside of the SqlClass that means that only the SqlClass can add a user. this would mean that the sql class must depend on the user class to know what a user is before it can add one. (you couldn't add apples and oranges, especially if you didnt know what an orange was)

Comment: The SqlClass does a require('User.class.php'); at the very first line. Sorry for not mentioning that.